# vim new shortcut, how?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

while on `:vert term`, I would like to switch between terminal and vim with `alt+q` instead of `ctrl+w+w`

how would I do that? What do I write after `:noremap` in `.vimrc`?

thank you in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nnoremap <M-q> :vert term<cr>
```